# Use threading to process file chunk by chunk

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp, snmp

I have a arraylist which consists of 5000 IP Addresses. For each IP Address, I want to execute a SNMPGet request and a FTPDownload command. I want to implement it in a fashion, wherein at a time 2 different threads run simultaneously for the first five IP Addresses. After the execution of these IP Addresses, next 2 IP Addresses will be executed on these threads. Can anyone help how to do it?

Here, connection is a class which extends the thread and the work to be implemented is written in its run() method. Please help.

```
Connection newConnection =new Connection(0);
Connection newConnection1 =new Connection(1);

for(int i = 0; i < NE_list.getRowCount(); i=i+2)
{
if(NE_list.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().equals("true")) //Some condition here for the IP Address
{

            newConnection.i=i;
            newConnection1.i=i+1;
            newConnection.runprogram();
            newConnection1.runprogram();
 }


    } 

class Connection extends Thread{
int  i;
Connection(int val){
  i=val;
}
void runprogram(){
start();
}
public void run(){
//SNMP and FTP Code here for IP Address in index i of NE_list
}
}
```

Comment: is there any reason you want to use only two threads?

Comment: Is there any reason to do this except for hacking purposes?

Comment: Take a look at  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5) and add your runnables to the returned ExecutorService

Comment: Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5) will really save you, do not create trheads, reuse them. Read file line by line and create jobs with line as parameter. pass these jobs to the Executors service and check the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executor Framework will be best suit for your solution. I have created one example here. You can increase the number of threads as per your requirement.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {
    int threadNo = -1 ;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public SomeRunnable(List list, int threadNo ) {
        this.list.addAll(list);
        this.threadNo =threadNo;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (String element : list) {
            System.out.println("By Thread:" + threadNo+", Processed Element:" +element);
        }
    }

}

public class ExecutorDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            list.add("Elem:"+i);
        }
        // Divide list 
        int divideIndex = list.size()/2;
        //Create objects of Runnable
        SomeRunnable obj1 = new SomeRunnable(list.subList(0, divideIndex),1);
        SomeRunnable obj2 = new SomeRunnable(list.subList(divideIndex,list.size()),2);

        //Create fixed Thread pool, here pool of 2 thread will created
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        pool.execute(obj1);
        pool.execute(obj2);

        pool.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Herewith adding working example having 5 threads. Just put the test.txt in your CLASS_PATH of the application.

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
List<List<String>> records;
MyRunnable(List<List<String>> records){
    this.records = records;
}
public void run(){
    for(List list : records){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : "+list.toString());
    }
}}
```

Main Class -

```
public class FileProcessThreads {
public List<List<String>> process(String fileName) throws IOException {
    List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        List<String> listValues = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
        records.add(listValues);
    }
    System.out.println(records.size());
    return records;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileProcessThreads fp = new FileProcessThreads();
    List<List<String>> records = fp.process("test.txt");
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    int recordsInEachThread = (int) (records.size()/5);
    System.out.println(recordsInEachThread);

    MyRunnable my1 = new MyRunnable(records.subList(0, recordsInEachThread));
    MyRunnable my2 = new MyRunnable(records.subList(recordsInEachThread+1, recordsInEachThread*2));
    MyRunnable my3 = new MyRunnable(records.subList(recordsInEachThread*2 + 1, recordsInEachThread*3));
    MyRunnable my4 = new MyRunnable(records.subList(recordsInEachThread*3 + 1, recordsInEachThread*4));
    MyRunnable my5 = new MyRunnable(records.subList(recordsInEachThread*4 + 1, records.size() - 1));
    es.execute(my1);
    es.execute(my2);
    es.execute(my3);
    es.execute(my4);
    es.execute(my5);
    es.shutdown();
}}
```

Comment: How do we do if i have to add files