# Parallelize sequential upload using multiple threads into s3?

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3

Concurrently, I am uploading multiple files to s3 like this:

```
public void put(String path, final BufferedImage ... images) {


        for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            final BufferedImage image = images[i];
            fileMapper.write(NAMESPACE, new String[] { path, Integer.toString(i) + ".png" }, new FileMapper.Writer() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I want to upload it by using multiple threads(several images at the same time). Can someone please help me and guide me that how can I do it?

Comment: Is the bottleneck your CPU or the network? i.e. which bottleneck are you trying to optimise for?

Comment: Have you tried adding these as tasks to a ExecutorService?

Comment: i am not an expert in this field so i have not tried that. can you please guide me how can i do that

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the concurrency tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Executor Framework from Java 5 or Fork/join from Java 7.

Pleae refer to following link for a sample.

[Executor Framework Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689245/use-threading-to-process-file-chunk-by-chunk/14869544#14869544)